# Click links and website pages on mobile devices using touchmove and touchend

Tags: javascript, html, touchstart, touchmove

hello i am a new student studying programmer. I was given a question from my lecturer to make a script with the question command: "click the link to another page in a paragraph when the phone screen is touched or swiped". I am very grateful for all the answers given by you guys. Thanks ..

this is my script

```js
<script>
$(document).on('touchstart', function() {
    documentClick = true;
});
$(document).on('touchmove', function() {
    documentClick = true;
});
$(document).on('click touchend', function(event) {
    if (event.type == "click") documentClick = true;
    if (documentClick){
        doStuff();
    }
 });
 </script>
```